# Sobolev inequality and C^{1,1} estimate

Tags: elliptic-equations, holder-spaces

I read in an article the following statement:
[image]

I  have  question about how we get the inequality (2.19)  :it is written that we  uses $C^{1,1}$ estimate but here $p\geq 2 $ and not necesserly bigger than number $n$. So I can't use the *Sobolev inequalities*. so could  you please give me an idea ?

Note that $B_{4}=\{x\in R^{n},|x|<4 \} $  and $\overline{\nabla u}=\int_{B_{4}}\frac{\nabla u}{|B_{4}|}$

Thanks for helping me